# A problem with the width of the second image

Tags: html, css

Please help me solve a problem with the width of the second image. I have put a link for you if you want to see what is the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Happy+Monkey&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Today is Violeta's birthday </h1>
    <img id="bff-img" src="Violeta.jpg">
    <h2 id="bday-age">38 years old</h2>
    <h4 id="bday-date">05.07.2022</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="gift-section">
  <h2 class="gift-title">Here's how happy I am for you today </h2>
  <h3 class="gift-hint">(Hover over the gift)</h3>
  <div class="gift-img" id="gift-img-happy"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="gift-section">
    <h2 class="gift-title">This one's for you, my friend </h2>
    <div class="gift-img" id="gift-img-cheers"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="gift-section">
    <h2 class="gift-title">How people react when you enter the room </h2>
    <div class="gift-img" id="gift-img-hot"></div>
  </div>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; 2022 </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is the css:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Happy Monkey', cursive;
    background: #a2d2ff;
    color: #ffffff;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
}

#bff-img {
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid #EFB0C9;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#bday-age {
    background: #EFB0C9;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

#bday-date {
    margin: 0;
    background: #EFB0C9;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.gift-section {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.gift-title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.gift-hint {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#gift-img-cheers {
    height: 200px;
}

.gift-img {
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url("9k=(1).jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#gift-img-happy:hover {
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQTMuMQnX7isJCCrCZbeh_JBp-ACk2KvmB1H7NBLp0V_Ty2988B&s");
}

#gift-img-hot:hover {
    background-image: url("9k=.jpg");
}

#gift-img-cheers:hover {
    background-image: url("birthday-beerthday.gif");
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

*Here is the link if you want to see my replit version:*
https://moms-birthday.starktrek.repl.co/

Tell me if my code isn't very good and what can I do be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you meant the height of the second image. In that case, just remove this style;

```
#gift-img-cheers{
    height: 200px;
}
```

because it is redundant and it's overriding the height of 400px from the gift-img class. I wouldn't recommend using the !important rule for newbies.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the problem very easy if you just add an "!important" behind the height: 400px; attribute. Like this:

```css
.gift-img {
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 400px !important;
    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url("9k=(1).jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The problem is that this attribute gets overwritten by this code:

```css
#gift-img-cheers {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the height of the second image ? if it does, it's because you already set height the image with css, just remove css rule inside #gift-img-cheers

```css
#gift-img-cheers {
    height: 200px; /* <-- remove this rule */
}
```

hope that help